# PHP add param at the beginning and end of every line from textarea

Tags: php

Im not familiar with PHP too much and I need to make a function that will read and add some string to every line from my textarea.

Example textarea

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

And what I need is

```
somestringAAAotherstring
somestringBBBotherstring
somestringCCCotherstring
```

and show it as output after sending "post".

EDIT:

My form is

```
<FORM METHOD ="POST">

<textarea rows="30" name="content"></textarea>

<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" VALUE = "Send">

</FORM>
```

and yes, question is "how to do it?"

Comment: So what's your question? And before you say, "how do I do it?", remember that questions like that are too broad and will be closed as such. So if you've written any code thus far I highly recommend adding it to your question. You should read "[how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = trim($_POST['textareaname']);
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind

foreach ($textAr as $lines) {
    $line = $sometext . $lines . $someOtherText;
//proceed furthur
}
```

Comment: their POST array is named `name="content"`

Comment: it is not a problem, change line to $text = trim($_POST['content']);